# Does the energy of a photon remain the same as the universe expands?

Tags: energy, cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, redshift

A team of two researchers far away from each other agree to perform a simple experiment. The first researcher emits a photon with wavelength $\lambda$ toward his colleague. As the photon travels to the second researcher, the universe expands by a factor of $a$.

The second researcher, now living in an expanded universe, measures the wavelength of the photon as $a \lambda$.

Did the energy of the photon remain the same throughout the expansion?

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The photon energy is given by $h \nu$ or $h c / \lambda$. Therefore, as the universe expands and $\lambda \to a \lambda$, the photon energy becomes $hc / (a\lambda)$.

The apparent violation of the conservation of energy seems worrying, but we should remember that in a spacetime whose metric evolves with time (such as the expanding universe you are considering), the total energy is not actually constant, because time-translation is no longer a symmetry of the system (so we can no longer use Noether's theorem to deduce conservation of energy). Sean Carroll has a good explanation of this: http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2010/02/22/energy-is-not-conserved/.